# Can I use a self-signed certificate on an AWS instance if the load balancer has a valid CA certificate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, cloudflare

We are using Cloudflare, which points to an AWS load balancer in front of an EC2 instance. The goal here is to have end-to-end encryption but I am trying to understand which parts of this setup actually require a certificate from a Certificate Authority, and whether or not we can use a complete set of free certificates between Cloudflare and AWS.

1. **Cloudflare** - We can use their free Universal SSL certificate to secure the traffic from Cloudflare to the load balancer.
2. **AWS Load Balancer** - We can use a free AWS certificate which is attached to the load balancer. This same certificate [cannot be installed on the EC2 instance](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/acm-ssl-certificate-ec2-elb/).
3. **EC2 Instance** - Can we use a self-signed certificate here, or do we need to continue purchasing certificates from a recognised authority? My understanding here is that, yes, we can just use a self-signed certificate and everything will be secure without raising any warnings about the self-signed nature of the certificate, as long as the load balancer has a valid CA certificate from Amazon or other authority.

Cloudflare is set to [Full SSL mode](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170416#h_845b3d60-9a03-4db0-8de6-20edc5b11057) which does not validate the origin certificate and will allow it to be self-signed, but I assume this only applies to the load balancer in our case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use whichever SSL you want on the instance, self signed or from a certificate authority.

By doing this the data will be encrypted in transit between your load balancer and the EC2 instance.

It is only the AWS services that require either an ACM cert or an uploaded cert from a valid certificate authority.

Ensure that your servers are kept private if you're using self signed certificates.

Comment: *"Ensure that your servers are kept private"* - could you explain what you mean by this please?

Comment: By this I mean, they should remain in a private subnet.

Comment: A private subnet is beyond my knowledge at the moment. What are the risks associated with a self-signed certificate if the server is not within a private subnet? My understanding was that a self-signed certificate is as secure as one signed by a CA, it just can't be validated as such by other parties.

Comment: This is more better practice for Load Balanced applications. By keeping your servers in private subnets they are not accessible without either a VPN, Direct Connect connection or by local routing within the VPC. By having your load balancer being the only public facing resource you are able to mitigate risks of your instances being compromised. Take a read of this for more info: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Scenario2.html

Comment: Okay, thanks. If I don't have a private subnet set up yet though, there's no difference in security if the certificate is self-signed or not though, right?

Comment: Not from the SSL, but yes for it being in the public space. Just make sure to keep your security groups tight :)

Comment: In this case, the SSL connection will terminate first at the ALB and then basically a new request will be created where the load balancer will act as client and the EC2 instance as a server. So how does the ALB trust the self signed certificate for this communication? Is my understanding correct?